# WebSockets server using Haskell

Tags: haskell, websocket

I want to write WebSocket server on Haskell. In the `websockets` package there is a `runServer` function. Example app uses it. But doc says that it must be used only in test apps, not in real.

How can I write simple template for my server using best practices and faster modern solutions? GHC 7.8.3.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://github.com/jaspervdj/websockets/blob/master/example/server.lhs) ?

Comment: Yes, I see. But in my question I asked "Example app uses it. (runServer)". By "Example app" I mean this link. And there I see `runServer`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a [ServerApp](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets-0.8.2.6/docs/Network-WebSockets.html#g:8) you can run it on Snap using [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets-snap-0.8.2.2/docs/Network-WebSockets-Snap.html) package. There's also a [WAI-related package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-websockets-3.0.0.1/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-WebSockets.html) which mentions the ServerApp type.